# How in Shopify add a user possibility for write manually the credit card info on chekout

Tags: shopify

I have an E-Store and on my products when a user tries to buy something, on the checkout is asking for PayPal payment. What I need is to allow the client to write his credit card information and pay in this way. 
I need to know how in Shopify add this way of payment to the user writes:
1) Credit card number
2) Expiration
3) CCV

Then pay

Answer (score 0):

That is built in to Shopify. In your Shop Admin. For checkout preferences. Simply inform Shopify of your credit card gateway.